# Selenium Webdriver: How to confirm element no longer displayed on page

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a table containing details about jobs.

Currently I can use the following code to find the specified job and select delete.

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void DeleteJob()
    {
        JobsPage.GoTo();          
        JobsPage.Delete("TestJobTitle");
        Assert.IsTrue(DeleteJobPage.IsAt, "Delete job page not displayed");            
    }
```

Below Method to find the specified job and click delete

```
public static void Delete(string delete)
        {
            var test = Driver.Instance.FindElement((By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr[td[2] = '" + delete + "']/td[9]/a[3]")));
            test.Click();
        }
```

I am now attempting to find a way to confirm the Job is no longer displayed on the JobsPage.

```
Assert.IsTrue(JobsPage._View("TestJobTitle"), "Job is still present");
```

The above Assert in the TestMethod is not working

I attempted the below method but need help to get working.

```
public static bool _View(string view)
        {
            IList<IWebElement> messages = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr[td[2] = '" + view + "']")).ToList();
            foreach (IWebElement message in messages)
            {
                if (message.Text == view) 
                {
                    return true; // Job is still present
                }
            }

            return false; // Job is not present

        }
```

Comment: view == view ??? what you trying to do ?

Comment: What is the problem? Have you debug to check each 'message.Text' yet?

Comment: Yes I checked each message.Text but it grabbed whole tr as a one line text. I tried grabbing the second td elements using Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr[td[2]")).ToList(); in hope to loop through its text property and compare to my string that is entering as a parameter in the above method but it fails as it couldn't find any webelements in it.

Comment: All I am trying to do is confirm a deleted job is no longer visible on the page.

Comment: Couldn't understand what you actually want to do. And which method is throwing exception. or not getting/finding elements.

Comment: Did you check your delete method is working fine or not. It is getting element and on click delete operation performing or not?

Comment: try to check with selenium command isDisplay or isVisible...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether this helps or not. I have same scenario and I do search in a table for a user still exists or not.

```
public static bool ValidateSearchResult(string s)
    {
        bool val = false;
        try
        {
            new WebDriverWait(Drivers._driverInstance, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.TagName("tbody")));
            IList<IWebElement> StatusColumnData = Drivers._driverInstance.FindElements(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr/td[2]"));

            foreach (IWebElement element in StatusColumnData)
            {

                if (element.Text.Contains(s))
                {
                    val = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    val = false;
               return val;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw (e);
        }
    }
```